# I can't sign commits from IntellIJ on windows using git from WSL2

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea, gnupg, wsl-2

Ok, so I have installed WSL2 Ubuntu on my Windows 10 pc. I'm trying to sign a commit from intellij (running as admin) installed on windows, and I'm using the git binary from the WSL2 vm, I have configured the gpg and git stuff in both windows and wsl, but I don't know why this is not working...

Here is a screenshot of the gpg signing working on the wsl vm.
[image: gpg working on wsl2]

And here I have another picture of the gpg signing working on the windows terminal.

[image: gpg working on windows]

The dialog showed successfully on both terminals asking for my passphrase. Using the git cli the gpg key works:

[image: manual commit working]

And this is the error I get:

[image: error on intellij]

Answer (score 2):

After some more research I found a workaround:

I found [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274528/GPG-Signing-does-not-work-on-WSL#focus=Comments-27-5149526.0-0) comment in the YouTrack site. Which led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474095/11622001) stackoverflow post. The workaround/solution is the following:

Edit the `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` inside your WSL setup and add the following line (or replace it if you already had a config with the same key):

> This config will tell gpg to use the windows gui instead of the cli when asking for your passphrase
>
> ```
> pinentry-program "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/pinentry-basic.exe"
> ```

You can keep the program path to the pinentry-basic.exe (that's the default one), but if you have it under another location make sure to change it.

After that you can try the following command and check that the windows pinentry dialog shows up:

> This command will sign the text "test" and will ask you for your key passphrase.
>
> ```
> echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
> ```

Comment: Wow, awesome thanks! This works perfect for me! After installing GitBase on my host Windows, my `pinentry` is in this directory: `pinentry-program "/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/pinentry.exe"`

Comment: Awesome! And yes, the pinentry program might be in different places depending on your setup and your system configurations. In this case yours is in the Program Files instead of the Program Files (x86), but I'm glad it worked :)