# GPG failed to sign the data for a git commit. But it works after signing a local file first?

Tags: linux, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnupg, wsl-2

This is a very weird behavior. I am using `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19`, and I am trying to sign a git commit. The first time I try I get an error saying:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

... but then someone suggested in another Stack Overflow question that if you sign a local dummy file first, and then try again to sign the commit that would work. And it does! But why? How can I avoid doing weird thing of signing a local file first every time I want to sign a git commit?

I am using WSL on Windows 11, so all these take place in WSL.

Comment: "*…if you sing a local dummy file first and then try again to sing the commit that would work. And it does! But why?*" Most probably because it successfully asks for a passphrase and caches it in `gog-agent` for a brief time period. While being called from Git it doesn't ask for a passphrase or it tries to ask and fails.

Comment: Try to switch to GUI `pinentry`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474095/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pinentry+wsl2

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know if this will solve it for everyone, the comments in the original question provide some other solutions that did not work for me. But I did find a solution in this [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#SSH_agent) in this section [Configure pinentry to use the correct TTY](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#Configure_pinentry_to_use_the_correct_TTY)

It was an issue where I had to specify the correct TTY as described in this [gpg-agent documentation](https://man.archlinux.org/man/gpg-agent.1)

So to achieve this I had added the following in my `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc` in my case when using `ohmyzsh`):

```
# update tty for gpg-agent
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
unset SSH_AGENT_PID
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```